# How to find tomorrow sold-out flights from HEL to RIX?

Tags: air-travel

I bought a ticket for tomorrow on 09:40 from HEL to RIX, but I cannot find my ticket, but not sure which company is travelling that time. There is no tickets more sold for the flight. 
So I want to know which flights are going tomorrow there, also those sold out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search for unavailable seats through Matrix ITA Software.  Make sure to unclick "Only show flights and prices with available seats":

[image: Screenshot page 1]

Tomorrow (9 April), there are 8 flights from HEL to RIX.  Three with Finnair, including one at 09:40, and five with Air Baltic.

[image: Screenshot page 2]

Comment: Great! Finnair is the right carrier.